# how to automatically sprintf elements of an array in a desired format

Tags: arrays, matlab, printf

I have many arrays with various number of columns, that is, I have many 1*m matrices with m varies from 1 to 20. For instance, consider these three hypothetical arrays:

```
 A1 = [1 14 20 8]
 A2 = [5 1 20]
 A3 = [2]
```

what I am after is creating a sprintf for each array to put together all array elements such that elements are separated by a dot. For the above examples, the desired outputs are

```
 1.40.20.8  % sprintf('%d.%d.%d.%d', A1(1,1), A1(1,2), A1(1,3), A1(1,4)); three dots required
 5.1.20      % sprintf('%d.%d.%d', A2(1,1), A2(1,2), A2(1,3)); two dots required
 2           % sprintf('%d', A3(1,1)); no dot required
```

It is certainly simpler if all of the arrays have same number of columns. But since it is not the case, I have no idea how to proceed. I just want an algorithm which automatically generates the sprintf for me with the correct number of dots.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to automate your process consists in find a way to automatically identify the arrays (A1, A2, ...) to be printed.

If you can not modify the code that generates the arrays in order to store them in a cellarray or in structure, you can do:

- get the list of the variables in the Workspace with the function `who`
- select the ones with the name `A` followed by an integer value using a `regexp`
- save these variables in a temporary file using `tempname` to generate the name of the temporary file
- load the temporary file in order to get a `struct` whose fields are the variables you want to print
- loop over the struct to print the variable
- to define the `sprintf` format with the right number of `%d` identifiers, you can user the `repmat` function along with the `length`
- optionally, you can store the string in a `cellarray` for further usage
- after the loop, delete the temporary file having previously set `recycle` to `on` to allow move the temporary file in the recycle folder

A possible implementation:

```
A1 = [1 14 20 8]
A2 = [5 1 20]
A3 = [2]

% Identify the desired variables
A_vars=who;
var_idx=regexp(A_vars,'A\d$');
idx=~cellfun(@isempty,var_idx);
% Create a temporary ".mat" file
tmp_file=[tempname '.mat'];
% Save the variables
save(tmp_file,A_vars{idx});
% Load the variables in a struct
A_vars=load(tmp_file);
% Loops over the varaibles to be printed
names_A=fieldnames(A_vars);
for i=1:length(names_A)
   % Get the length of the current array
   n=length(A_vars.(names_A{i}));
   % Create the sprintf format
   fmt=repmat('%d.',1,n);
   % Print the current variable in a string
   str=sprintf([fmt],getfield(A_vars,(names_A{i})));
   % Remonve the last "."
   str(end)=[];
   % Store the strings for further usage
   list_of_vars_string{i}=str;
   % Disp the current variable
   disp(str)
end
recycle('on')
delete(tmp_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strsplit` and `strjoin` on `num2str` output which produces space-separated strings from numerical vectors:

```
A{1} = [1 14 20 8];
A{2} = [5 1 20];
A{3} = [2];

for ii = 1:numel(A)
    str = num2str(A{ii});
    str = strjoin(strsplit(str),'.');
    disp(str)
end
```

outputs:

```
1.14.20.8
5.1.20
2
```

Answer (score 0):

[`sprintf`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) format specifier is automatically reused as many times as necessary if the second input is an array. That is, `sprintf('%i.',A1)` gives `1.14.20.8.`. Once this is done, it only remains to get rid of the final dot, which can be accomplished via indexing. So,

```
A1 = [1 14 20 8];
result = sprintf('%i.',A1);
result = result(1:end-1);
```

gives

```
result =
1.14.20.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A1 = [1 14 20 8] ;
fprintf([repmat('%d.', 1, size(A1, 2)-1),'%d' '\n'],A1)
```